# How can we read memory mapped file data of 32 bit 3rd party application from a windows service application?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, windows-services, memory-mapped-files

I have a 32 bit third party application's dll. It is of type library project and creates a memory Mapped File named **MappedObject**. This is the section of code indicating generation of mmf file:-

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "dllmain.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <ctime>


#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

#define BUF_SIZE 48

HANDLE hMapFile;
LPCTSTR memoryBuf;
TCHAR szName[] = TEXT("MappedObject");
/**
 */
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
        hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(hMapFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, BUF_SIZE, szName);

        if (hMapFile == NULL)
        {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Could not create file mapping object (%d).\n"),
                GetLastError());
            return FALSE;
        }
        memoryBuf = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,   // handle to map object
            FILE_MAP_WRITE, // read/write permission
            0,
            0,
            BUF_SIZE);

        if (memoryBuf == NULL)
        {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
                GetLastError());

            CloseHandle(hMapFile);

            return FALSE;
        }
        }
        break;
```

Now there is a 2nd C# application which must read this memory mapped file. The C# application is of type Windows Service. This is a section of code :-

```
 try
            {
                MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(@"Global\MappedObject", MemoryMappedFileRights.ReadWrite, HandleInheritability.None);
                Library.WriteErrorLog("Mapped File Accessed");
                MemoryMappedViewAccessor mmfViewStream = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(0, MMF_MAX_SIZE, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[MMF_MAX_SIZE];
                String message = String.Empty;
                while (mmfViewStream.CanRead)
                {
                    mmfViewStream.ReadArray(0, buffer, 0, MMF_MAX_SIZE);
}
```

Whenever the 2nd application i.e. c# application tries to access memory mapped file. It cannot find it. 
What really is weird is that If I build a simple console application and try to access the memory mapped file, I can. However, there seems to be a problem in windows service type application. Can anyone please point to me in right direction??

**For your information, the mapped file name is MappedObject and I have tried to access it through MappedObject, @"Global\Mapped" in my service application. However, it doesn't seem to work. I am on Windows 10 64bit. The 3rd party application is of 32 bit. The service application is also of 32 bit(I am using x86 release feature of visual studio of build).**

Comment: It looks to me like the 3rd party is NOT creating the MMF using the "Global\" prefix - so it can't be seen from a different session (e.g.. a service).

Comment: @MatthewWatson If it's not then I have tried using the name MappedObject  which is the same name as in 3rd party object memory mapped file as well..but I am still not able to access it..

Comment: TEXT("MappedObject") is certainly wrong, that needs to be `TEXT("Global\\MappedObject")`.  It worked from the console mode app because they both run in the same session.  And you surely ought to fret about timing, a service normally starts too soon and there is no hint whatsoever how the service could possibly detect that DLL getting injected into a user session process.  Other than "it isn't there".

Comment: Thank you Hans for your reply...I will perform the changes. Actually, there is a third party application which utilizes the above dll to send some commands and their results in mmf. My application is trying to read the results from mmf. I missed the Global\\ part. I willt try it and thank you for explaining to me why it worked for the console application. Thumbs up for that...:)